# Scale MySQL trigger for thousands of inserts per seconds

Tags: mysql, trigger, deadlock, performance, python, performance-tuning

We are using MYSQL database for an Analytics app. I have two table `token` and `token-big` (for overview of actual data) both have `id(int) unix_starttime(int) unix_endtime(int) details(varchar 256)`

A row is added to table `token` every second using *python MySQLdb*. I have an after insert trigger on `token` table which does the following:

1. Get the latest entry (last) from `token-big`'s
2. If `unix_starttime` of newly inserted row (in `token`) is no more than 5 seconds apart from `unix_endtime` from `token-big`:

   - update `unix_endtime` of last row in `token-big` to `unix_endtime` of newly added row in `token`
   - else insert new row in `token-big` same as the newly added row in `token`

This works fine for a few `token` `token-big` table pairs but I start to get deadlocks if these pairs (tables) are in number of hundreds.

How can I scale this method? Is there any better alternative?

I don't wish to use `events` as it may delay the data shown to user. Same goes for background jobs which run every few minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `TRIGGER`.  Instead, gather a minute's worth (say) of data in a staging table.  Then do the desired updates en masse.  If you need the user to get up-to-the-second information (instead of just up-to-the-minute), have the user's query do that final update also.

To phrase it differently, summarization is much more efficiently done in bulk.

Your statements are confusing on the scale of the problem:  "thousands of inserts per second" versus "a row is added to table token every second".  Which is it?

If serious scaling of inserts and processing, see [my blog on staging tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  That discusses "ping ponging" of a pair of staging tables in order for the speed to be self-adjusting.

To discuss *your* situation further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some more details.

Comment: By "thousands of inserts per second" i meant concurrent inserts to different tables every second. (1 row is inserted to 1000 different tables every second). I will benchmark results with insert + update with same query. thanks for your answer

Comment: It is rare to see a schema design that needs 1000 tables.  So, I question the wisdom of that aspect.  Please elaborate.  Do not give each user (or widget or whatever) its own identical table.  But them all in the same table.  (Or small set of dissimilar tables.)

Comment: But at that rate a single table will have 86 million entries every day. data retrieval from such a big table will also take too much time. hence those many tables. let me know if my understanding about mysql performance is incorrect.

Comment: A billion-row table handle some queries in milliseconds.  Other queries will take hours.  Let's see the `SELECTs` you need to run.

Comment: For Detailed event i use. `SELECT details, unix_starttime, unix_endtime FROM $token WHERE unix_starttime >= $START_DATE AND endtime <= $END_DATE limit 500;`

Comment: for visually displaying the data [example](http://imagebin.ca/v/20z8ds9904hg) i use `SELECT unix_starttime, unix_endtime FROM $token_big WHERE unix_starttime >= $START_DATE AND endtime <= $END_DATE LIMIT 50;`

Comment: That particular `WHERE` does not optimize well, regardless of the values and `INDEXes`.  If there are fewer than 50 matching rows, it will have to scan much of the table.  Can the time ranges (unix_start/endtime) overlap?  If not, there is a fix.

Comment: overlap in a row or column ? they might overlap column vise (endtime of ID 1 might be starttime of ID 2). there is no check on row (starttime = endtime) but that can be added.

Comment: "How many rows is this exact time in?"  If the answer can be >1, then the start..end pairs are overlapping.  If there are no overlaps, I have a much more efficient way to store and access the data; see [my IP-ranges blog|(http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).  It talks about IP ranges, but time ranges would work equally well.  If you have overlaps, there is no solution (that I know of).

Comment: i am using Amazon Web Service btw is there any service which can be used for this ? like SNS, SQS + Lymbda etc. i am not sure how to proceed and their documentation is too general. Thanks for your time